# Is this a legal SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a schema like this

```
...
Event(Name, Date, TotalSeats)
Reservation(EventName, Date, NumSeats)
...
```

I want to extract the total number of seats available for each event, is the following query a legal way to do it?

```
SELECT R.EventName, (SELECT TotalSeats
                     FROM Event
                     WHERE Name = R.EventName) - SUM( NumSeats )
FROM Reservation R
GROUP BY EventName;
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: I'd say NO. (There's no table P, so there's no column P.EventName available to select.) Also beware, the sub-select is not allowed to return more than 1 row!

Comment: @jarlh Edited that. The problem of translating a schema on the spot (it was in italian "Prenotazione P" <-> "Reservation R"... Sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more traditional way to write this query would use `join`:

```
SELECT r.EventName, e.TotalSeats - SUM( r.NumSeats )
FROM Reservation r JOIN
     Event e
     ON e.Name = r.EventName
GROUP BY r.EventName, e.TotalSeats;
```

Your version should work in MySQL, assuming there are no duplicates in the `Event` table.

Comment: your solution seems way cleaner than mine... I thought of a join, but had a doubt about what to put in the group by. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The query which you have written in your sub-query..

```
SELECT TotalSeats FROM Event WHERE Name = R.EventName
```

can consist of more than one records.. so in that case this query will return error..

Comment: I should have specified that Event.Name is primary key